# Is there any way I can allocate PrivateIP from my Host's Machine network subnet to an Openstack instance

Tags: cloud, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon, private-cloud

Consider I am currently residing in an organization X which has its own network and subnet(172.16.0.0/16) from which it assigns a privateIP to each machine in organization.
I have an instance(Ubuntu) assigned to me and on that I am running open-stack and my machine private IP is 172.16.34.56/32.

On my instance I have installed open-stack and through that have  launched some VMS.

My Question is can i assign my organization one of private IP to VMs running on open-stack, so that it can be accessed from any where with in organization.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible to assign your machine private n/w (172.16.34.56/32) to the openstack VMs, in that case, it would be a provider n/w for your openstack VMs.

To accomplish this, you have to add your machine private n/w interface to the below configuration while installing neutron.
File Name: /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/linuxbridge_agent.ini 
Add that interface here,
[linux_bridge]
physical_interface_mappings = provider:PROVIDER_INTERFACE_NAME

Be Cautions while adding a provider n/w subnet. It should not overlap with any existing used IP addresses or subnet.